# Hartshorne, Exc II 7.9: Do I need regularity to show $\operatorname{Pic} \mathbb P(E) = \operatorname{Pic} X \times \mathbb Z$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, projective-schemes

Exercise II 7.9 (a) in Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry* is

> Let $X$ be a regular noetherian scheme, and $E$ a locally free coherent sheaf of rank $\geq 2$ on $X$.
>
> 1. Show that $\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic} \Pic \mathbb P(E) \cong \Pic X \times \mathbb Z$
> 2. If $E'$ is another locally free coherent sheaf on $X$, show that $\mathbb P(E') \cong \mathbb P(E)$ (over $X$) if and only if there is an invertible sheaf $L$ on $X$ such that $E' \cong E \otimes L$.

First note that for 1. we clearly need that $X$ is connected, otherwise we would get more factors of $\mathbb Z$. So let's assume $X$ is connected.

I wonder if I need the regularity of $X$ to show part 1. Here is how my proof goes:

Denote by $\pi: \mathbb P(E) \to X$ the canonical map and consider the sequence
$$\tag{$*$} 0 \to \Pic X \xrightarrow{\pi^*} \Pic \mathbb P(E) \xrightarrow{|_F} \Pic F \to 0,$$
where $F = \pi^{-1}(x_0) \cong \mathbb P^n$ is some fiber. If we can show that this sequence is exact we are done, because $\Pic F \cong \mathbb Z$, so the sequence splits. Clearly the restriction to $F$ is surjective, because $\mathcal O_\pi(1)|_F$ generates $\Pic F$. So we even see that the splitting $1 \mapsto \mathcal O_\pi(1)$ is canonical.

To show that the pull-back $\pi^*$ is injective, I don't have a really good argument which fits the scope of the exercise, but this is certainly true. For example this is part of the splitting principle (cf. Fulton, *Intersection Theory*, Corollary 3.1). Does anyone know of a simpler argument?

Clearly ($*$) is a complex, the pull-back of a line bundle is trivial on the fiber $F$. To see the exactness in the middle, let $L$ be any line bundle on $\mathbb P(E)$ that restricts to the free sheaf $\mathcal O_F$. Then $L$ is also free in a neighbourhood $V = \pi^{-1}(U)$ of $F$. In particular, the set
$$Y = \{\,x \in X : L|_{\pi^{-1}(x)} \cong \mathcal O_{\pi^{-1}(x)}\,\}$$
is open. Twisting $L$ with $\mathcal O_\pi(1)$ we see that the sets
$$\{\,x \in X : L|_{\pi^{-1}(x)} \cong \mathcal O_{\pi^{-1}(x)}(d)\,\} = \{\,x \in X : (L \otimes \mathcal O_\pi(-d))|_{\pi^{-1}(x)} \cong \mathcal O_{\pi^{-1}(x)}\,\}$$
are open as well. Clearly those sets form a disjoint open cover of $X$, so the connectedness yields $Y = X$. So we can obtain an open affine cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ such that $V_i = \pi^{-1}(U_i) \cong U_i \times \mathbb P^n$, and there are sections $s_i: \mathcal O_{V_i} \xrightarrow{\cong} L|_{V_i}$. The transition functions
$$g_{ij} = s_i^{-1} \circ s_j \in \Gamma(V_i \cap V_j, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)})$$
are pull-backs of functions $f_{ij} \in \Gamma(U_i \cap U_j, \mathcal O_X)$ (if $X$ is separated this follows from Prop 5.13, I hope this is still true in general?), which define a line bundle $M$ on $X$ such that $\pi^* M \cong L$.

So I don't think I need that $X$ is regular for this (at least if $X$ is separated). Did I make a mistake?

It could be that we only need the regularity in part 2., I still have to think a bit more about that.